# DateFormat in Table using C# not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures, html-table

I am trying to pull data from a SQL database using a stored procedure with the results populating a table in an ASP.net page using a Placeholder:

Here is the code:

```
tbl.Append("<tr style='cell-padding: 2px'>");
tbl.Append("<td>" + rdr[0] + "</td>");
tbl.Append("<td>" + rdr[1] + "</td>");
tbl.Append("<td>" + rdr[2] + "</td>");
tbl.Append("<td>" + rdr[3] + "</td>");
tbl.Append("<td>" + rdr[4] + "</td>");
tbl.Append("<td>" + rdr[5] + "</td>");
tbl.Append("<td>" + rdr[6] + "</td>");
tbl.Append("</tr>");
```

Here is the result.

```
First Name  Last Name   Team    Manager Return Date Return  Addendum
Firstname   LastName    Team    Manager 11/17/2014 0:00 Yes Doc.pdf
```

I can't seem to get the Return Date to only be: 11/17/2014

Comment: You likely need to retrieve the column as `DateTime` and convert it to a string, e.g.  `rdr.GetDateTime(4).ToShortDateString()`

Comment: You would have to format the date either in the SQL or in your code.  This is not the best way to display data in C#, you can use data table or something else.

Comment: @DanWilson, I appreciate the comment, I am quite new to this and this is helping me learn,

do you mean tbl.Append("<td>" + rdr.GetDateTime(4).toShortDateString() + "</td>");

Comment: @Brad, I appreciate the advise, learning this as I go.

Comment: If you want to convert date on the SQL side you could use one of these:  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: Yes, if the date is in column four (I can't tell for sure).

Comment: @Dan Wilson, based on your direction I got it to display as desired. Thank you so much for your assistance....

Answer (score 0):

You can use string interpolation with a format specifier.  It's difficult to decipher which column has the date in it so let's just go with `rdr[3]`.  You can use a [custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) like I did here, or use a [standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.85).aspx) that will vary the result based on what your system settings are such as locale.

```
{
tbl.Append("<tr style='cell-padding: 2px'>");
tbl.Append($"<td>{rdr[0]}</td>");
tbl.Append($"<td>{rdr[1]}</td>");
tbl.Append($"<td>{rdr[2]}</td>");
tbl.Append($"<td>{rdr[3]:MM/dd/yyyy}</td>");
tbl.Append($"<td>{rdr[4]}</td>");
tbl.Append($"<td>{rdr[5]}</td>");
tbl.Append($"<td>{rdr[6]}</td>");
tbl.Append("</tr>");
}
```

Or you can use `tbl.Append(string.Format("<td>{0:MM/dd/yyyy}</td>",rdr[3]));`  Interpolation is just a shorthand way to call string.Format.

Using this type of formatting is preferable over calling a ToString() method on the object since it always works. A null will just be converted to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 rdr[3].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```